# Center site in the center of the screen

Tags: html, css, center

How can I center the whole site in the center of the screen?

Both horizontally and vertically;

This is [the site](http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/85unG/55/embedded/result/), see that it is centered horizontally, vertically now missing (any resolution)

Feel free to modify the source at [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/85unG/55/).

Answer (score 2):

```
#container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -200px auto auto -200px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scyRT/).

Comment: Tried to put these changes in # wrap did not work.

I came to study how to do it on the web, but am not able to apply it on this site.    http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/85unG/55/

Comment: @Riderman The CSS *does* work, refer to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85unG/58/).

Comment: CSS does not work.
The alignment is totally wrong, both horizontally and vertically