# Horizontal alignment with CSS

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
<div class="one">
   <p>Test<p><span style="color: Green">▼</span>
</div>
```

This is a really easy question I think but I don't know CSS. How can I make the paragraph appear aligned horizontal in the center?

Comment: This is duplactes of many questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972017/center-site-in-the-center-of-the-screen do a couple of search in stackoverflow first and then ask your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues here.

1. To center the DIV that contains the paragraph.
2. To center the paragraphs that come within the DIV.

To center the DIV, here's the code using inline styling:

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto" class="one">
    <p>Test<p>
</div>
```

The above will center the whole DIV but NOT align the text to the center. Again, the div will only get centered if the class "one" has a width specified. Otherwise, it has no effect. You can also include the margin style info inside the class named "one".

Now, to align all text that appear within the DIV horizontally, you can style it like this:

```
<div style="text-align: center" class="one">
    <p>Test<p>
</div>
```

And if you want to apply the centering style only for a single paragraph, you can include the the style rule within the `<p>` tag.

Comment: I tried this but my code has a span and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Welcome... Also note this - for making layouts, you may find using DIVs better than SPAN. Use spans for smaller things like formatting a block of text within a paragraph or data fields within a row.

Answer (score 1):

The margin solution with margin auto is suitable for floating block elements, but if it is only text within normal html you should look at this example here:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text-align_all

Answer (score 1):

you can use all of the following approaches

```
.One{text-align:center;}
```

or

```
.One p{margin: 0 auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS.
`margin:auto`

Comment: WHere do i add it ?  I want just horizontal alignment. Does this do vertical also?

Comment: Sorry I just noticed my code didn't appear because i did not click code. Now my question is better.

Answer (score 0):

your page should have this on it at the top inside the `<head>` tag

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .one p {text-align:center;}
    </style>
```

If you want to center the entire div, and not the text, use this but be sure to set a width for the div.

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .one p {margin:0 auto; width:300px;} /*Change the width to what you need to*/
    </style>
```

For vertical alignment, look into http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/vertical-alignment-css/